# How to search with 'LIKE' condition for two tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have small laravel project working on search with `LIKE` condition from 2 same structure tables. Below is example

```
Table1                    
id         name           
1          Ryan Cole
2          Bailey Henderson

Table2                   
id         name           
1          Anna Henderson
2          Corey Allen
```

Sorry that I no code, but below dummy is result that I need.

A) Search single query with word `'Henderson'`, the expect result should be:

```
[ {'id':2, 'name':'Bailey Henderson'}, {'id':1, 'name':'Anna Henderson'} ]
//because of 'Henderson' contain on both table.
```

B) Search with word `'Ryan'`, result should be:

```
[ {'id':1, 'name':'Ryan Cole'} ]
//because of 'Ryan' only contain in table1.
```

C) Search with word `'Corey'`, result should be:

```
[ {'id':2, 'name':'Corey Allen'} ]
//because of 'Corey' only contain in table2.
```

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Please include your PHP and/or SQL code.  We can't really help you without seeing that.

Comment: Dear Tim Biegeleisen, I earlier note that I have no code but just only expected result present. Btw, It's not pure PHP, Its laravel instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried "union" in query builder?

```
$a = DB::table("table1")
    ->select("table1.id", "table1.name")
    ->where('name', 'like', "%$searchTerm%");

$b = DB::table("table2")
    ->select("table2.id", "table2.name")
    ->where('name', 'like', "%$searchTerm%");

$a->union($b)
  ->get();
```

Comment: Dear Akm, Thank you very much.